# Spring context property-placholder ehcahe configuration

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I have a spring context xml file with this

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:cacheConfig.properties"/>

<bean id="cacheManager"
    class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="cacheManagerName" value="cacheName"/>
    <property name="shared" value="false"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:cacheConfig.xml"/>
</bean>
```

the goal is to allow the customer to edit the properties file, like this

```
cache.maxMemoryElements="2000"
```

and then in the actual cacheConfig.xml file have this

```
<cache name="someCacheName"
   maxElementsInMemory="${cache.maxMemoryElements}" ... />
```

so that items we do not want the customer to change are not exposed.  Of course the above details are only partially detailed and NOT working.  Currently I see this in the log file

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Error configuring from input stream. Initial cause was null:149: Could not set attribute "maxElementsInMemory".
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your example uses `EhCacheManagerFactoryBean` to expose a reference to the `CacheManager`, with caches defined in the external `cacheConfig.xml` file. As @ChssPly76 pointed out, Spring's property resolver only works within Spring's own bean definition files.

However, you don't have to define the individual caches in the external file, you can define them right within the Spring bean definition file, using [`EhCacheFactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/cache/ehcache/EhCacheFactoryBean.html):

> FactoryBean that creates a named
>   EHCache Cache instance... If the
>   specified named cache is not
>   configured in the cache configuration
>   descriptor, this FactoryBean will
>   construct an instance of a Cache with
>   the provided name and the specified
>   cache properties and add it to the
>   CacheManager for later retrieval.

In other words, if you use `EhCacheFactoryBean` to refer to a named cache that isn't already defined in `cacheConfig.xml`, then Spring will create and configure a new cache instance and register it with the `CacheManager` at runtime. That includes specifying things like `maxElementsInMemory`, and because this would be specified in the Spring bean definition file, you get full support of the property resolver:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:cacheConfig.properties"/>

<bean id="myCache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>
    <property name="maxElementsInMemory" value="${cache.maxMemoryElements}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="shared" value="false"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:cacheConfig.xml"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks! That gets me over the hump enough that I can get to the point that I'd like.

Comment: What if you want to configure something that is not a cache?  For example, a property of cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory?

Answer (score 3):

This is not how PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer works. It can be used to replace values **within context**, but not within arbitrary external files. And `cacheConfig.xml` is an external file - it's just being passed by Spring to EH Cache.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Maven or Ant, both offer the ability to do filtering of tokens in resource files.

For Maven, you could do something like

```
<cache name="someCacheName"
  maxElementsInMemory="${cache.maxMemoryElements}" ... />
```

And in a filter file, or in the POM itself, have

```
 cache.maxMemoryElements = 200
```

[Resource Filtering in Maven: The Definitive Guide](http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-description.html)

With Ant, you do this with [FilterSets](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterset.html) and the `<copy>` task.

Comment: +1, but important thing to keep in mind here is that with both Ant and Maven property replacement occurs during **build time** as opposed to Spring's property placeholder where it happens during runtime.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who needs to modify the diskstore path which cannot be set as the ehcache javadoc states that the diskstore parameter is ignored, you could create   your own implementation of a EhCacheManagerFactoryBean, which allows you to inject the diskstore path; you basically need to intercept the creation of the CacheManager and modify the configuration passed along using your diskstore property, e.g.:

```
private String diskStorePath;

...getter/setter


public void afterPropertiesSet() throws IOException, CacheException {
    if (this.shared) {
        // Shared CacheManager singleton at the VM level.
        if (this.configLocation != null) {
            this.cacheManager = CacheManager.create(this.createConfig());
        }
        else {
            this.cacheManager = CacheManager.create();
        }
    }
    else {
        // Independent CacheManager instance (the default).
        if (this.configLocation != null) {
            this.cacheManager = new CacheManager(this.createConfig());
        }
        else {
            this.cacheManager = new CacheManager();
        }
    }
    if (this.cacheManagerName != null) {
        this.cacheManager.setName(this.cacheManagerName);
    }
}

private Configuration createConfig() throws CacheException, IOException {
    Configuration config = ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(this.configLocation.getInputStream());

    DiskStoreConfiguration diskStoreConfiguration = config.getDiskStoreConfiguration();
    if (diskStoreConfiguration == null) {
        DiskStoreConfiguration diskStoreConfigurationParameter = new DiskStoreConfiguration();
        diskStoreConfigurationParameter.setPath(getDiskStorePath());
        config.addDiskStore(diskStoreConfigurationParameter);
    } else {
        diskStoreConfiguration.setPath(getDiskStorePath());
    }

    return config;
}
```

The Spring config then looks like this:

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="com.yourcompany.package.MyEhCacheManagerFactoryBean" depends-on="placeholderConfig">
    <property name="diskStorePath" value="${diskstore.path}"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml" />
</bean>
```

Comment: just to add to this for me helpful post: if you need to access a jndi property you can set it via: <property name="diskStorePath" value="$jndi{property/ehcache/diskstore}"/>